# Can't get my input value to be used in the subsequent calculation in Python

Tags: python, input

I'm completely new to python and not sure what I have done wrong.

```py
value = int(input("Enter your value in radians: "))

pi = 3.141592653589793238
num1 = 180

if (value > 0):
    print("The answer is:" + value*pi/num1)
else:
    print("Incorrect input")
```

Comment: You should use a code block to present your code. Anyhow, the problem is that you are trying to concatenate the result of `value*pi/num1` with thr string `The answer is` and that do not work. Change the previous to `str(value*pi/num1)`

Comment: try using this for print =>   `print(f"The answer is:  {value*pi/num1}")`